# Scheduler Module unpublish content

Tags: 8, cron

Trying to schedule a content type to be unpublished on a specific date. Using the scheduler module everything is set up seemingly correct. When I run Cron the update fails,

- Updater Content - Publishing status complete. Results: No updates were performed. 1 updates were invalid
- When i go to Scheduled Updates Overview and run scheduled updates manually it works just fine.

Why is Cron Failing?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a drush command to run only the scheduled_updates_cron() function from the command line and also from crontab. I didn't know why all of my updates were invalid till I saw your post, so I made some research and I managed to make my drush command work like the "Run Updates" button from Scheduled Updates Overview page, by specifying the user who should run the update.

Example (Wrong results): `drush command-name`

Example (Good results): `drush --user=1 command-name`

If you are using the `drush cron`command, you should modified it to `drush --user=1 cron`

I hope this helps !